# Triggering different intents with the update permission event

Tags: node.js, push-notification, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

My question is surrounding asking a user permission for 2 different things.

Currently I have an intent that asks for the users location, I have another intent `user_locate` with the Event `actions_intent_PERMISSION`. This intent performs a bunch of logic after the user allows location access.

I'm creating a new intent, that I want to use to send push notifications to the user with. This requires me to again ask the users permission - is there a way for this permission request to fire a *different* event? Or do I essentially need to handle all `actions_intent_PERMISSION` events in a single intent?

Thank you.

edit: would [this](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/functions-cron) be a suitable solution for scheduling push notificatins?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple, only peripherally related, questions in a single SO question. Bonus Question 1 is a reasonable, although difficult, question that deserves to stand on its own. Bonus Question 2 should be rephrased to make it less opinion based as a stand-alone question. In both, provide additional details of how you're attempting to do it, including code if appropriate, and why you are asking the question.

Comment: I removed them I realize that makes the question more difficult and abstract I'll break them out separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the same Event in different Intents. You'll need to set the Context at the same time you send the permission request to differentiate between the two different requests. So when you send the location request you could also set the `requestLocation` Context with a short lifespan and when you send the notification request you would also set the `requestNotification` Context with a short lifespan as well.

You would then have Intents that might look something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Prisoner, in your answer you mention "a short lifespan". Is there a reason to have a lifespan longer than 1?

Comment: Good question. When asking for permissions, possibly not, since I think you always get a response either way. In general, however, users may respond to you with a response that may not be relevant (asking for help, no response, etc), so you generally want to keep a context alive for a bit until you're sure it isn't relevant, at which point you can clear it.

Comment: (If you have further questions about this - perhaps asking them as a new SO question might be best.)